# append null character at the end of file using cmake

Tags: string, file, null, cmake, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate  files using cmake and append a null character(`\0`) at the end of output file. Does anyone know how to append null at the end?
The code for concat is :

```
function(cat in_file1 in_file2 out_file)
     file(READ   ${in_file1} CONTENTS)
     file(WRITE  ${out_file} "${CONTENTS}")
     file(READ   ${in_file2} CONTENTS)
     file(APPEND ${out_file} "${CONTENTS}")
endfunction()
```

To append `'\0'` at the end I've tried following approaches :

```
file(APPEND ${out_file} NULL)
file(APPEND ${out_file} "\\0")
file(APPEND ${out_file} "\0" HEX)
```

But none of these 3 work. Can anyone help here ?

Comment: Do you want to have the final file as with the text as it is seen in the input files or in HEX (e.g. the final file: 6369616f2c20736f6e6f0a73692c73690a7365636f6e646f2c206a6a6a6a0a6563636f6c6f20696c207365636f6e646f0a00)? If you want it as a text, why do you want to append the null character at the end? If you want in HEX that's another story.

Comment: Did you try `file(APPEND ${out_file} "\0")`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful : yes. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @fedepad : I want it as a binary file consisting of all text and last character as null. The flow is that there's a C++ program that reads this file as a string and it's expected to be null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following instead of what you have?

```
function(cat in_file1 in_file2 out_file)
        file(READ   ${in_file1} CONTENTS HEX)
        file(WRITE  ${out_file} "${CONTENTS}")
        file(READ   ${in_file2} CONTENTS HEX)
        file(APPEND ${out_file} "${CONTENTS}00")
endfunction()
```

this should append a null byte at the end of the generated hex string. Then I don't know how to go from there.
There is some work in this direction but I don't know other examples. I think both the linked examples can be useful to solve your case:

[binary_to_hex](http://www.codegists.com/snippet/cmake/bin2hcmake_sivachandran_cmake)
[embed_binary_files](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/blob/master/CMakeModules/EmbedBinaryFiles.cmake)

Comment: thanks for reporting it! Did you check out the links I provided? Maybe you can get some inspiration from them....

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked the links yet. Will check those and report back. Thanks.