# Is there a way to generate a string with NUL byte in CMake?

Tags: cmake

In CMake there's `file(READ <filename> <variable> HEX)` command, which can be easily used to read contents of a binary file into a variable as a hex string. However there's no opposite version of the function, as `file(WRITE ...)` takes a string and writes that directly. With a bit of CMake code you can easily convert a hex string into a list of decimal numbers, so I was hoping to be able to use `string(ASCII ${bytes} bytes)` to convert that to raw binary, but CMake doesn't like that idea when there's a zero value in the string:

```
CMake Error at sha-256.cmake:40 (string):
  string Character with code 0 does not exist.
```

What I try to accomplish is to calculate a SHA-256 of the compiled executable, save that to a file as a binary data, convert that into an object file (with `objdump`) and link the executable again (this is for an embedded project with a bootloader, which uses SHA-256 embedded in the firmware to verify its integrity). The script I wrote works perfectly fine as long as the SHA-256 hash has no byte of value 0 in it and I cannot think of any way to overcome this CMake limitation...

Below you may find a simplified script which demonstrates the problem.

```
function(hexadecimalToDecimal hexadecimal decimal)
    set(result 0)
    foreach(i RANGE 1)
        math(EXPR result "${result} * 16")
        string(SUBSTRING "${hexadecimal}" ${i} 1 character)
        if(character STREQUAL "a")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 10")
        elseif(character STREQUAL "b")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 11")
        elseif(character STREQUAL "c")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 12")
        elseif(character STREQUAL "d")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 13")
        elseif(character STREQUAL "e")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 14")
        elseif(character STREQUAL "f")
            math(EXPR result "${result} + 15")
        else()
            math(EXPR result "${result} + ${character}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(${decimal} ${result} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# this is what I really do with this script
# file(SHA256 ${INPUT} sha256)

# this works fine
# set(sha256 "ffc950af6ce0ef4cf1b4984f9111b31714062e7c401ae0e81b22a0ec226e3823")

# this doesn't work
set(sha256 "00c950af6ce0ef4cf1b4984f9111b31714062e7c401ae0e81b22a0ec226e3823")

foreach(i RANGE 0 62 2)
    string(SUBSTRING ${sha256} ${i} 2 hexadecimalByte)
    hexadecimalToDecimal(${hexadecimalByte} decimalByte)
    list(APPEND bytes ${decimalByte})
endforeach()
string(ASCII ${bytes} bytes)
file(WRITE ${OUTPUT} ${bytes})
```

To test:

$ cmake -D OUTPUT=sha-256.bin -P sha-256.cmake

The form above produces an error, but changing the `sha256` string to a version with no `00` at the beginning causes the whole thing to work perfectly.

Is there any way this can be accomplished in CMake or should I just do that in a shell script or in Python?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm afraid you did not read my question... I'm using this command, but for my particular use-case I need to convert the output of that command (a hex string `001122aabbcc...`) into a binary representation.

Comment: There are so many different things in your question, so I actually have read only some of them. Sorry. Looks like CMake simply doesn't support null characters in variables. Probably, because some build tools have bad support for such variables. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514723/append-null-character-at-the-end-of-file-using-cmake)(not answered) about null character in the string.